# bad revision on bash_completion.sh file, now I can't boot

Tags: raspbian

```
younghoons-MacBook-Pro:~ younghoonkim$ ssh pi@192.168.10.110
pi@192.168.10.110's password: 
Linux raspberrypi 4.14.79-v7+ #1159 SMP Sun Nov 4 17:50:20 GMT 2018 armv7l

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Wed Dec 12 12:26:13 2018
/usr/local/bin/nfc_read_run: line 3: /var/run/doornfc.pid: Permission denied
NFC reading ready...
Connection to 192.168.10.110 closed.
```

I tried to include one of my script to run right after booting, but seemed like I did something wrong. nfc_read_run file seems to be running but doornfc file is another file that nfc_read_run is running, and there's permission problem. Now I can't login on my Pi.... This is result of ssh to Pi.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You wrote: "*I tried to include one of my script to run right after booting*". How? What script? Just revoke it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pi is booting fine since you can initiate an ssh session. You’ve run a script that results in a permissions error and it kills your ssh session. You now have little choice but to go directly to the pi and either boot into recovery mode and delete or fix your script or pull the sd card and put it in another computer then delete or fix your script that way.